# ERROR: pygame.error: video system not initialized

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working through a python book. So far, all of the programs have worked, but now I'm stuck. I typed in the program, and I'm getting this error when I run it. I checked all of the lines several times, and I think everything's right. It is supposed to open a text window and 10 seconds later show a game character. At first, I  had an indent error, but I fixed that. Now I'm getting this new error. it starts up and runs for about 0.5 seconds, but it immediately closes and gives this error. I'm using Python 3.8.10 On Windows 10 Pro 64-bit and this is the error: **pygame.error: video system not initialized** and here is the code:

```py
import pygame
import time
import subprocess
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 250))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)

pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 200)

def text_generator(text):
    tmp = ""
    for letter in text:
        tmp += letter
        if letter != " ":
            yield tmp
class DynamicText(object):
    def __init__(self, font, text, pos, autoreset=False):
        self.done = False
        self.font = font
        self.text = text
        self._gen = text_generator(self.text)
        self.pos = pos
        self.autoreset = autoreset
        self.update()

    def reset(self):
        self._gen = text_generator(self.text)
        self.done = False
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        if not self.done:
            try: self.rendered = self.font.render(next(self._gen), True, (0, 128, 0))
            except StopIteration:
                self.done = True
                time.sleep(10)
                subprocess.Popen("python C:\\Users\\david\\Documents\\pythonbook\\pygame1.py 1", shell=True)

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.rendered, self.pos)
text=("Steve has gone on a quest to defeat the Ender Dragon. Will he make it?")

message = DynamicText(font, text, (65, 120), autoreset=True)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: break
        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT: message.update()
        else:
            screen.fill(pygame.color.Color('black'))
            message.draw(screen)
            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick(60)
            continue
        break

    pygame.quit()
```

How can I figure out what the error message means? Or does anyone know?

Comment: You quit the game in every frame (`pygame.quit()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You quit the game in every frame with `pygame.quit()`. quit the game after the application loop instead of in the application loop. Also why do you update the game just in the else case? The `break` statement in case of `event.type == pygame.QUIT` only breaks the event loop, but not the application loop. Change the control flow of your code:

```py
# application loop
run = True
while run:
    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: run = False
        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT: message.update()
        
    # redraw in every frame
    screen.fill(pygame.color.Color('black'))
    message.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

# quit after the application loop
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: hey, I solved the problem! I just added time.sleep(60) right before pygame.quit and it worked perfectly!

Comment: @GMDDirvelin Sorry, but that makes absolutely no sense. ` time.sleep(60)` just makes the game sleep for 60 seconds.  `pygame.quit()` will still be executed and `if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  break` still does not work.

Comment: it's been longer than a minute and it's still going

Comment: i can move my character left and right perfectly

Comment: i found a second solution. sys.exit()

Comment: @GMDDirvelin With you "solution" only the game in the subprocess works ("pygame1.py"), but this application doesn't work.

Comment: @GMDDirvelin it's great that you're trying out ideas, but you really should go back through that book and try to understand what each line of code really means, and in your head try to walk through the logic of the 'if'  'for' 'while' blocks. try to think how the code moves from one line to the next at each momement in time.  this is called "stepping through the code" and you do it with a debugger.  if your IDE doesn't have this, i recommend a different IDE because it will really help you to understand how code jumps into and outside of blocks and repeats.

Comment: @GMDDirvelin and in particular, look at Rabbid76's #comments.    They help break down the code into sections and Rabbid76 put them there so you could understand the parts of the program, not because they 'make it work'.